# How to listen for new keys using Redisson

Tags: redis, redisson

I need to listen to a keyspace for new, removed and updated values. I can see how the last two are achieved, following Redisson's object oriented approach.

Can someone clue me into how I would do the equivalent of this, using Redisson?

```
CONFIG SET notify-keyspace-events KEA
PSUBSCRIBE __keyspace@0__:*
```